# Change a UITextField keyboard type base on condition

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a UITextField with a UISegmentedControl above that. I made a condition if UISegmentedControl is 0:

```
txtExample.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.phonePad
```

Or, if UISegmentedControl is 1:

```
txtExample.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
```

In my UIViewController storyboard, because it only has one UITextField, I only set numbersAndPunctuation.

It did not work because it always shows numbersAndPunctuation only, whatever is choosen on the UISegmentedControl

What is the correct code to show correct keyboard type base on condition for only one UITextField?

Remember, I already put `txtExample.delegate = self` before in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Show us your code work.

Comment: just same like usual segmented control, just add keyboard type based on selected

Comment: make sure on clicking the segment, you have to resign keyboard.

Comment: @dahiya_boy did you mean reloadInputViews()?

Comment: What do meant by inputView? Please show your entire code otherwise I cant help.

Comment: if (CustomUserDefaults.shared.getHeaderContactCase() == 0) {
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            txtExample.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.phonePad
        } else if (CustomUserDefaults.shared.getHeaderContactCase() == 1) {
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
            txtExample.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
        }

Comment: Add this in your post (as it is part of question) with proper code format.

Comment: @Sarimin Did you create an _Action_ for `UISegmentedControl` and use that to change the input type for the textField ?

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi, yes I create action, and after that I saved into user default

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the _Action_ part code

Answer (score 0):

This below code is working fine,

```
if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
    myTextField.keyboardType = .phonePad
}
else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
    myTextField.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
}
```

**Output gif:**

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you go for **ternary operator** instead of this _if-else_ like `myTextField.keyboardType = sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? .phonePad : .numbersAndPunctuation`

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi What difference it make ??

Comment: Just good coding practices. I mean it's the ideal condition for using a _ternary operator_

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I dont think so, what if OP wants to do more coding based on index?  **Ternary operator** operator good if you just wanted to change value which is not too complex to get. Like you wanted to toggle value but you got that value after writing more than 1 LOC.  You cant be sure about whether OP just want to change the keyboard type or may he also doing some more code based on index.

Comment: I said that because there was only 2 index values and 1 line of code (inside if-else condition) in _your answer_ . That's why I said **it's the ideal condition for using a _ternary operator_** . That **it** meant in your answer's context .

Comment: but in my case it always called keyboard type from storyboard, not from code

Comment: @Sarimin Everything is working fine as expected. If you facing issue with same then probably you made any  mistake and you unable to track.